# Class which provide "Selection"

Tags: c#, selectall

Is there any class which provide basic selection mechanism? for example:

Imagine I have WAVE file and simple WAV-Editor written in C#. Now I can display this wave file in graphical representation as wave form. In main menu I can click Edit -> Select All, which will select all my samples.

```
 MySelector ms = new MySelector (0, numOfSamples-1);
 ms.SelectAll;
```

Ofcourse Ishould can select range block:

```
ms.Select (from, to);
```

Or even invert:

```
ms.InvertSelection ();
```

Multi select:

```
ms.AppendSelection (from ,to);
```

Get information about selected samples:

```
for (int i=0; i< ms.Size; i++)
if (ms.SelectedAt (i)) DoSomeLogic ();
```

So, is that class already written or should I do it tommorow :O ?

Thx.

Comment: Separate your logic from your UI. There is no "Select" class or "ISelected" interface, because UI elements that can be selected will handle their own selection. You can then retreive `ListBox.SelectedItems()` and work on this list.

Answer (score 1):

I've not been able to find any "official" (built into the framework) classes which vaguely match what you describe, but I've found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19028/Building-a-Generic-Range-class) which should help you on your way - I can't see an equivalent to your `InvertSelection()` method but apart from that it looks promising.

Edit: Upon further searching, I've found that Jon Skeet has a chapter on creating your generic range class in his book C# in depth - see an extract of it on his site [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/Ranges.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything in the framework that does only this. It seems like something that would be highly dependent on how you want to keep track of the selections (`Selected` property, Range of indexes).

Answer (score 1):

How much of this class do you have written already? As it is, I see that you *describe*

1. a set of two numbers (longs, perhaps?) to define a time range or sample selection.
2. The ability to select all times/ samples as a convenience.
3. a collection of time ranges .
4. the ability to "hit test" a given time/sample for selectedness.

If you have an API/ POCO for your wave data, you might implement a generic or visitor pattern on it to get the functionality you need. I'm not sure I know of a general purpose "sample range" item within the .net framework.

As an example, though, you might take a look at the code sample at [Building a Generic Range class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19028/Building-a-Generic-Range-class) to see if you can make some use of it. I'm not totally sure I agree with some of his operator overloading, but it may be a place for you to start.